# Did you know she was in Berlin? vs You knew she was in Berlin? How to differentiate?

Tags: словоупотребление

The two sentences I wrote in english roughly translate to

> Did you know she was in Berlin? (Asking a genuine question)
>
> You knew she was in Berlin? (And you didn't tell me?!, accusing the other person)

I think `Вы знали, что она была в Берлине?` is how you would translate the first sentence, but how would you imply the second one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Did you know she was in Berlin? (Asking a genuine question)

If she was in Berlin before he supposedly knew it (i.e. did he know in 1990 that she was in Berlin in 1975):

```
Вы знали, что она была в Берлине?
Знали ли вы, что она была в Берлине?
Известно ли было вам, что она была в Берлине? (most formal)
```

If she was in Berlin at the same time he supposedly knew it (i. e. did he know in 1990 that she was at Berlin in 1990)

```
Вы знали, что она в Берлине?
Знали ли вы, что она в Берлине?
Известно ли были вам, что она в Берлине? (most formal)
```

> You knew she was in Berlin? (And you didn't tell me?!, accusing the other person)

```
И вы знали, что она (была) в Берлине?
```

or, even better:

```
Она была в Берлине, и вы это знали?
```

Answer (score 5):

Your second sentence is nonstandard in English, it's colloquial.As for forming sentences containing a reproach or a sort of accusation, we use both affirmative and interrogative sentences supporting them with intonation and words increasing expressiveness(I am not going to consider English sentences была или есть.)

> **Так** Вы знали,что она в Берлине? И не сказали мне? or *Как*? Вы знали, что она  в Берлине?

We can repeat words, pause emphatically

> Вы...,Вы знали, что она в Берлине и *ничего* мне не сказали?

The first question is pronounced with a rising intonation and sounds neutral.

> Знали ли Вы,(Вы знали),что она в Берлине?

Answer (score 3):

First things first, tense sequencing. "Did you know she was in Berlin?" is **Вы знали, что она в Берлине?** No **была**, which would make it "did you know that she *had been* to Berlin".

And the most natural and economical way to differentiate between question and accusation would be with intonation alone:

> Вы ↗↗**знали**, что она ↘в Берлине? *(question)*
>
> Вы знали, что она ↗**в Берлине**? *(accusation)*

(The double arrow is a makeshift way to indicate that that pitch rise is greater than the other one and the drop.)